# how to reboot Jenkins slave in pipeline without job failed

Tags: jenkins

Here is the thing, I have got a program that may get stuck sometimes, and when it happens I need to reboot my machine.
So, I want to reboot my Jenkins slave when the program gets stuck then continue to execute the rest  of my program without marking the whole job as failed.

Can Anyone tell me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I wanted to add this as a comment but I don't have enough reputation.
You may want to use Restart from stage feature as documented [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/running-pipelines/)